# Sorting issue in .NET

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, sorting

I am using this linq query to sort a string column but the results I am getting does not seems to be in right order?

**Query:**

```
userList = users.OrderBy(u => u.FirstName)
                .Skip(offset)
                .Take(rowcount)
                .ToList<User>();
```

**Result:**

> rama &
>   11Rama
>   15rama
>   1Rama
>   2Rama
>   490110rama
>   IU-Rama
>   Rama

it should be something like?

> 1Rama
>   2Rama
>   11Rama
>   15rama
>   490110rama
>   IU-Rama
>   rama &
>   Rama

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: is this LINQ-to-{some database backend}? if so: what is the database collation?

Comment: Is what you are displaying the FirstName field?

Comment: @MarcGravell we are using Entity Framework.

Comment: @Ali great; now what is the database collation?

Comment: @jle Yes its FirstName field.

Comment: @MarcGravell It seems that I do not have permissions to view its properties, I'll get back to you once I get the permissions.

Comment: @Ali `select DATABASEPROPERTYEX  ('yourdbname', 'Collation')`

Comment: @MarcGravell it's SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.

Comment: @Ali are you sure the first one doesn't have leading space? i.e. `" rama"`

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes, there are no leading spaces I've copied the text and place it in notepad to make sure.

Comment: Can you describe the sorting rules you want? Right now your example looks inconsistent.

Comment: @DanielBrückner It's just an example the rule is simple Numeric first then alphabetic like we souldn't have 'rama &' at first position.

Comment: But numbers before letters means 11Rama should come before 1Rama, you example has it the other way round.

Comment: Ideally 2Rama should come after 1Rama and 15Rama should come after 11Rama.

Comment: I've made changes to example given.

Comment: Now it is a natural sort order and neither SQL Server, AFAIK, nor the .NET framework offers this. You will have to do the sorting on the client and provide your own comparer implementation. See the example in Abolfazl Hosnoddin's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting your result sorted by the code points of the characters and that is by far the most common implementation for sorting strings. What you are expecting is called natural sort order, see for example this [article](http://blog.codinghorror.com/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order/), but you will have to do it on your own because .NET does not provide this out of the box.

Comment: The expected results listed is not a natural order sort.  Notice how in his *expected* results 15 comes before 2.

Comment: You are right. On a closer look it is actually inconsistent - 1 before R for the first letter (1Rama < Rama) but R before 1 for the second letter (1Rama < 11Rama).

Comment: Yes.  I was confused by that as well.

Comment: I am accepting this answer since the sort order require in this case is natural sort order. Thank you @DanielBrückner.

Answer (score 0):

By adding this code you will be able to sort as you need it to be done. But this sorting will be done on client side and all records must be fetch as list.

```
userList = users.ToList<User>()
            .OrderBy(u => u.FirstName,new NumericComparer())
            .Skip(offset)
            .Take(rowcount)
            .ToList<User>();

public class NumericComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        return StringLogicalComparer.Compare(x, y);
    }
}

public class StringLogicalComparer
{
    public static int Compare(string s1, string s2)
    {
        //get rid of special cases
        if ((s1 == null) && (s2 == null)) return 0;
        if (s1 == null) return -1;
        if (s2 == null) return 1;

        if ((s1.Equals(string.Empty) && (s2.Equals(string.Empty)))) return 0;
        if (s1.Equals(string.Empty)) return -1;
        if (s2.Equals(string.Empty)) return -1;

        //WE style, special case
        bool sp1 = Char.IsLetterOrDigit(s1, 0);
        bool sp2 = Char.IsLetterOrDigit(s2, 0);
        if (sp1 && !sp2) return 1;
        if (!sp1 && sp2) return -1;

        int i1 = 0, i2 = 0; //current index
        while (true)
        {
            bool c1 = Char.IsDigit(s1, i1);
            bool c2 = Char.IsDigit(s2, i2);
            int r; // temp result
            if (!c1 && !c2)
            {
                bool letter1 = Char.IsLetter(s1, i1);
                bool letter2 = Char.IsLetter(s2, i2);
                if ((letter1 && letter2) || (!letter1 && !letter2))
                {
                    r = letter1 ? Char.ToLower(s1[i1]).CompareTo(Char.ToLower(s2[i2])) : s1[i1].CompareTo(s2[i2]);
                    if (r != 0) return r;
                }
                else if (!letter1) return -1;
                else return 1;
            }
            else if (c1 && c2)
            {
                r = CompareNum(s1, ref i1, s2, ref i2);
                if (r != 0) return r;
            }
            else if (c1)
            {
                return -1;
            }
            else
            {
                return 1;
            }
            i1++;
            i2++;
            if ((i1 >= s1.Length) && (i2 >= s2.Length))
            {
                return 0;
            }
            if (i1 >= s1.Length)
            {
                return -1;
            }
            if (i2 >= s2.Length)
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }

    private static int CompareNum(string s1, ref int i1, string s2, ref int i2)
    {
        int nzStart1 = i1, nzStart2 = i2; // nz = non zero
        int end1 = i1, end2 = i2;

        ScanNumEnd(s1, i1, ref end1, ref nzStart1);
        ScanNumEnd(s2, i2, ref end2, ref nzStart2);
        int start1 = i1; i1 = end1 - 1;
        int start2 = i2; i2 = end2 - 1;

        int nzLength1 = end1 - nzStart1;
        int nzLength2 = end2 - nzStart2;

        if (nzLength1 < nzLength2) return -1;
        if (nzLength1 > nzLength2) return 1;

        for (int j1 = nzStart1, j2 = nzStart2; j1 <= i1; j1++, j2++)
        {
            int r = s1[j1].CompareTo(s2[j2]);
            if (r != 0) return r;
        }
        // the nz parts are equal
        int length1 = end1 - start1;
        int length2 = end2 - start2;
        if (length1 == length2) return 0;
        if (length1 > length2) return -1;
        return 1;
    }

    private static void ScanNumEnd(string s, int start, ref int end, ref int nzStart)
    {
        nzStart = start;
        end = start;
        bool countZeros = true;
        while (Char.IsDigit(s, end))
        {
            if (countZeros && s[end].Equals('0'))
            {
                nzStart++;
            }
            else countZeros = false;
            end++;
            if (end >= s.Length) break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yikes! Please please please try and use better variable names!

Comment: I got this code many years ago from net. I works and that matters.

Comment: I agree with you. But sometimes some codes must be treated as 'Black Box'. It does what we need so why to focus on that code?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a custom IComparer would work for you.

Check this implementation: http://zootfroot.blogspot.com/2009/09/natural-sort-compare-with-linq-orderby.html

You code would then call `myLinqQuery.OrderBy(item => item.sortProperty, new MyComparer<string>())`

In his example, the sort order return:

```
image1.jpg
image4.jpg
image30.jpg
image200.jpg
```